# Attempting to solve the twin paradox without acceleration

Tags: special-relativity, relative-motion

My teacher told me that the key to solve the twin paradox is acceleration of the one that travel away. However, I feel a little bit uncertain that time change significantly by just a slightly nudge of acceleration. So I tried to prove it without the acceleration:

The twin paradox stated that given two twins A and B. A is at rest relative to the Earth and B hop on a spaceship and travel away to a point in space and then come back. Suppose the distance that B planed to travel is $L$ (relative to A-the Earth) and B is travel at a velocity $v<c$. Consider A's reference frame, A notice that his brother will travel in a period of time $t$ with $t=\frac{2L}{v}$. However, A learned relativistic mechanics and calculated that the time his brother experiences (denoted as $t'$) will be less than him thus $$\gamma t'=t \,\,\,(with\,\,\,\, \gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v²}{c²}}})$$.

In B's reference frame, however, his $L'$ is not equal to $L$ - as his brother see, since a fixed distance $L$ from the Earth to somewhere (for example Mars) is moving relative to him as he travel. So we apply the Lorentz transformation and get $L=\gamma L'$, furthermore, B sees the the Earth (or the destination hes traveling to) moving relative to him with velocity $-v$. Thus B can calculate the time he will travel is $t'=\frac{L'}{v}=\frac{L}{\gamma v}=\frac{t}{\gamma}$ $$=> \gamma t'=t$$ So both A and B calculate and measure the same interval of time that B will travel, thus there is no paradox and B will be younger than his brother. Is my proof valid? I'm open to any suggestion and comment, thanks for reading.

Comment: Note that if $t$ is proper time, then $t'=\gamma t$ or $t=\frac{t'}{\gamma}$ and not $\gamma t'=t$. The primed observer sees the ticks on the moving clock take _longer_ than ticks on his clock.

Comment: You are not proving anything. The twin paradox is a direct prediction of SR and not at all a problem requiring solving. If you are already using SR (since A used SR to calculate what B sees, and then B also uses SR to deduce both length contraction and the time that A sees), of course you can find a way to explain the difference, but then that is a tautology. The logic is backwards.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen  I believe your solution is essentially equivalent as what is suggested here: https://www1.phys.vt.edu/~jhs/faq/twins.html Check out the last section ("...without acceleration") then read the rest to fill in the gaps.